# Difference between throttle(int power) and getSpeed():int in a UML diagram?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I'm trying to create a class from a UML diagram and the interface description is confusing me as I'm not sure how to declare the last two methods for the Engine interface.

I know that the first two are methods so they will be declared like `void stop();` and `void start()`;

But how do I declare the other methods in the interface?
This is how I've declared the class, I'm wondering if this is correct?

```
public interface Engine {

    void stop();
    void start();
    void throttle(int power);
    int getSpeed();

}
```

This is the UML description of the interface:

[image: Engine Interface UML]

Comment: Your Java code looks correct but the UML diagram is broken.  It should read `throttle(power : int)`.  As for the instance variables, I'm not quite understanding your question.  There are no instance variables shown in the diagram.  However, there is a second mistake related to this: If there are no attributes, then there should still be two horizontal lines (ie a very tight empty box) above the box containing the methods.

Comment: @5gon12eder Does it also need to be `throttle(int power) : void`?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `f(...)` is equivalent to `f(...) : void` but I could be wrong on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a correct translation of the UML diagram element into Java code.

`getSpeed() : int` means "getSpeed is a method that takes no arguments and returns an int". Unlike in Java, UML specifies types of things after their name (so you should also have `power : int` instead of `int power`).

Comment: I'm wondering also what the `throttle()` and `getSpeed()` methods should do? Doesn't seem to clear from the UML what they should do. So for example when I implement the `Engine` interface from my  `CombustionEngine` class the method `public void throttle(int power) is declared but there is no definition as to what it does also the same for `public int getSpeed()` as it just returns zero.
 `

Comment: The UML diagram doesn't say what they should do. You need to get that information from somewhere else.